# Draw nodes distributed on a full line width with the middle one filling the remaining space

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, nodes, textwidth

I am trying to achieve the following result:
[image: goal]

which is:

- a `tikzpicture` that fills the entire `textwidth`
- a `Node A` of `4cm` on the `left` with the text aligned on the left
- a `Node B` of `5cm` on the `right` with the text aligned on the right
- a `Node C` filling the entire remaining horizontal space between `A` and `B` keeping a margin of `1cm` on each side with centered text

---

For now, I can achieve very little, and I'm sure there is a far better way of doing it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {rectangle, fill = red!30, text = red}]
\path (0, 0) -- (\textwidth, 0);
\node[minimum width = 4cm, anchor = north west, align = left] (a) at (current bounding box.north west) {Node A};
\node[minimum width = 5cm, anchor = north east, align = right] (b) at (current bounding box.north east) {Node B};
\node[anchor = center, align = center] (c) at ($(a)!0.5!(b)$) {Node C};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

which leads to:

[image: output]

- I currently use a `path` to have my `tikzpicture` fills the entire `textwidth` but I'm not sure it's the correct way of doing it
- The text is not correctly aligned on the `left` and on the `right`
- I have no idea how to obtain the result I want for the middle node

The whole example can be rewritten from scratch if it was not at all the way to proceed.

---

**QUESTION**: How can I achieve the result I want for my `tikzpicture`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jasper isn't wrong but makes it much more complicated than it is.

This obviously has hard-coded values for `4cm` and `5cm` (and the `1cm` between nodes) but it takes the `inner xsep` into account without having to explicitly state it. (But you can still change it as an parameter to

```
\tikzMe[inner xsep=5pt]{Node A}{Node C}{Node B}
```

I've chosen `align=flush left` and `align=flush right` to suppress some warnings about underfull hboxes – unless you want multiline nodes there.

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\tikzMe[4][]{%
  \par\noindent\tikz[baseline=+0pt,#1]
    \node[
      align=flush left,
      anchor=base west,
      text width={4cm-2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}]{#2}
     node at(\textwidth,0) [
       align=flush right,
       anchor=base east,
       text width={5cm-2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}]{#4}
     node at(5cm,0) [
       align=center,
       anchor=base west,
       text width={\textwidth-11cm-2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep})}]{#3}
       ;\par}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\tikzMe[nodes={rectangle, fill = red!30, text = red}]
  {Node A}{Node C}{Node B}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses standard LaTeX lengths to calculate the width of the center node. To align the node excactly in the middle of the two outer nodes, use the anchors `east` and `west` as reference, not the center of both outer nodes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {rectangle, fill = red!30, text = red}]
\path (0, 0) -- (\textwidth, 0);

\node[minimum width = 4cm, anchor = north west, align = left] (a) at (current bounding box.north west) {Node A};
\node[minimum width = 5cm, anchor = north east, align = right] (b) at (current bounding box.north east) {Node B};

\newlength{\midnodelength}
\setlength{\midnodelength}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\midnodelength}{-11cm} % = -(4cm + 5cm + 2 * 1cm)

%%% alternatively you can use \pgfmathsetlength:
% \pgfmathsetlength{\midnodelength}{\textwidth - 4cm - 5cm - 2 * 1cm}
%%%

\node[minimum width=\midnodelength, anchor = center, align = center] (c) at ($(a.east)!0.5!(b.west)$) {Node C};

\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This results in three nodes having the correct widths. However, from the picture you post, it seems that you want to get nodes where the text is aligned to the left, right or center. Additionally, these nodes should probably have some inner padding, so that the text does not stick to the border.

To achieve this, you need to do some calculation. Ti*k*Z offers the option `text width` which you can use to set the width to the inner box of the node that contains the text. Alignment will then work as expected, but a node will by default have some `inner sep` which is added do the node width. So, if you want to keep this `inner sep`, you need to subtract this from the `text width`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {rectangle, fill = red!30, text = red}]
\path (0, 0) -- (\textwidth, 0);

\node[inner sep=5pt, text width={4cm - 10pt}, anchor = north west, align = left] (a) at (current bounding box.north west) {Node A};
\node[inner sep=5pt, text width={5cm - 10pt}, anchor = north east, align = right] (b) at (current bounding box.north east) {Node B};

\newlength{\midnodelength}
\pgfmathsetlength{\midnodelength}{\textwidth - 5cm - 4cm - 2 * 1cm}
\node[inner sep=5pt, text width={\midnodelength - 10pt}, anchor = center, align = center] (c) at ($(a.east)!0.5!(b.west)$) {Node C};

\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you add the following line below the `tikzpicture`, you can see that the widths of the nodes (and the gaps) are now correct:

```
\noindent\rule{4cm}{3pt}\rule{1cm}{1pt}\hfill\rule{1cm}{1pt}\rule{5cm}{3pt}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. And what to do for text alignment? The text of Node A and Node B are not correctly aligned (they should be aligned left and right).

Comment: @Vincent Sorry, I didn't pay attention to that. I edited my answer.

Comment: text width = 4cm seems to produce a node that is a little longer than 4cm. I want the rectangle to be exactly 4cm.

Comment: @Vincent Try with `inner sep=0t, outer sep=0pt`

Comment: @Vincent I enhanced my answer to explain a bit about the inner mechanics of width (and height) measurement of Ti*k*Z nodes. I hope it helps to solve your issue.